# What is the name of the last song that plays in this video?

Tags: music, sengoku-basara

Does anyone knows if the last song used in this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kT-inxMKC4) which is labeled 'Kojuro' something can be found in any of the anime ost?

Video description:

> ニコ動より
>
> 曲目（と動画編集時のイメージ）
>
> ■BLAZE ～Crimson Lotus～：真田幸村（殴り愛）
>   ■Heaven's Door：伊達政宗（UMA）
>   ■Shut up～Go to Hell：猿飛佐助（姫抱き）
>   ■水光に映る従夢：片倉小十郎（こじゅと自然）？

Comment: Sounds like a remixed version of "[Suikou ni Utsuru Juumu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OarWQCP5qrs)" (水光に映る従夢) with a faster tempo and boom baps.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably track #10 on the album [Sengoku BASARA Ongaku Emaki ~Ao-ban - It's Show Time!~](http://vgmdb.net/album/16709) (VTCL-60117). The title of the piece is "[Suikou ni Utsuru Juumu] featuring Katakura Kojuurou".

You can listen to a sample at [its Amazon Japan page](http://www.amazon.co.jp/TV%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%80%8C%E6%88%A6%E5%9B%BDBASARA%E3%80%8D%E9%9F%B3%E6%A5%BD%E7%B5%B5%E5%B7%BB~%E8%92%BC%E7%9B%A4-It%E2%80%99s-Show-Time-~/dp/B001XXJFGS/) (or [the full version on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXuYu6SVPew), but this may disappear at any time).

Comment: Yes that is the one, however I would prefer if there is one with the voice actor in the song